# Why for restarting primitives need to send a Hex index? OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I have this two array.
This array contains a vertices position:

```
static const GLfloat strip_position[] =
{
    -4.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //0
    -3.5f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //1
    -3.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //2
    -2.5f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //3
    -2.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //4
    -1.5f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //5
    -1.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //6
    -0.5f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //7
     0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f   //8
};
```

This array contains a  indices of vertices:

```
// Indices for the triangle strips
static const GLushort strip_indices[] =
{
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
};
```

And I draw them as follows:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 9, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
```

I see this:
[image]

Cool. I represented exactly this.

But, When I add a Restarting primitives function:

```
glPrimitiveRestartIndex(4);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 9, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
```

I think, that 5,6,7,8 should displayed. But I saw it:
[image]
Where are 5,6,7,8 ?? Okey. I done this:

```
static const GLushort strip_indices[] =
{
    0, 1, 2, 3, 0xFFFF, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
};
```

Draw Command:

```
glPrimitiveRestartIndex(0xFFFF);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 10, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
```

And I saw it:
[image]
How do like this:
[image]

Comment: I got it! I used this: `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);` I don't know, why my vertices became to draw a clockwise.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that you needed to use a hex index? You can assign **any** index you want to the primitive restart index, whenever that index is encountered in your element array it will restart the primitive. **`0xFFFF`** is frequently used because it is the largest possible index and therefore unlikely to collide with anything. It is shorthand (though for a 16-bit number it does not really save any typing) for 65535.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is *Face-culling*. OpenGL by default assumes, that all objects (triangles, etc...) are specified in a counter-clockwise order. This is correct for your first vertex array and all the others you can see.

For the part with vertices 5, 6, 7, 8 it is drawn clockwise. OpenGL then assumes this is the backside of an object and will not draw it.

To get around this, you can reorder your vertix indices to `0, 1, 2, 3, 0xFFFF, 5, 7, 6, 8` or disable backface-culling completely.